# Check File Extension in android

Tags: java, android, file

i made a small method to check whether defined folder has files with a specific extension or not. I m getting null point exception on run.pls help to find mistake.method is checking .mp4 files and returning true if found and message is displayed.

Here is Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView filecheck;

        filecheck = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filecheck);

        filecheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (accept()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Files Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Files Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean accept() {
        final File pathname = new File("/sdcard/test/");
        String files[] = pathname.list();
        System.out.println(files.length);
        for (String s : files) {
            if (s.contains(".mp4")) {
                System.out.println(s);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: jss.testmethods, PID: 23659
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at jss.testmethods.MainActivity.accept(MainActivity.java:38)
                      at jss.testmethods.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show the logcat with the NullPointerException and tell which code line causes it.

Comment: `pathname.list()` might return null. And so the null pointer exception. Check before use.

Comment: `s.contains(".mp4")`. Better: `s.endsWith(".mp4")`.

Comment: i changed path to  final File pathname = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); still same error.

Answer (score 0):

i was expecting simple error, i missed to add permission for read storage. it is working now.